# What are the different builder widgets(Future Builder, Stream Builder, Layout builder, Listview Builder) in Flutter.?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I want to know all the builder widgets and its main differences (Future Builder vs Stream Builder?) and where to place them exactly. An example with the Builder widget may be easy to understand. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its a huge topic by the way. First you need to clear your understanding about "Future" and "Stream".

Comment: @Robin I'm so much exited about these different builders and curious to learn. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FutureBuilder behaves identically to a StreamBuilder configured with future?.asStream(), except that snapshots with ConnectionState.active may appear for the latter, depending on how the stream is implemented.

A StreamBuilder can be used with data of Firebase, Sensor Events and Network Connection status

Following link will better understanding of how future and stream works : [Information about future and streams in dart](https://dev.to/allanjeremy/explain-futures-and-streams-in-dart-like-im-five-46nd)

FutureBuilder and ListView Builder, eg:
Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getPosts(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Loading..."),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                  ),
                  CircularProgressIndicator()
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["title"]),
                    onTap: () => navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]));
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

StreamBuilder and ListView Builder, eg:
Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("posts").snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Loading..."),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50.0,
                    ),
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                              snapshot.data.documents[index].data["title"]),        // getting the data from firestore
                      ),
                   );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Note:** The only problem i got through using FutureBuilder is not whenever i added the data in using FutureBuilder, the data was not getting fetch properly. While using StreamBuilder i was not having the same problem it worked properly.

Comment: @YasasSandeepa I've added the example

Comment: I really appreciate your great help. Thank you so much @Yash Jain